# How to execute ruby code in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have the following code in my products/index.hmtl.erb:

```
<a href="/assets/shop/shop-item.html" class="item-quick-view" 
data-lightbox="ajax"class="icon-zoom-in2"></i><span> Quick View</span></a>
```

What it should do is to open a quick view window about the product. 
Problem is, the ruby code in the html is not excecuted, so it shows up as text:

```
<%= @product.title %>
```

Renaming the file to html.erb did not help. Then the ajax window does not open.

What is the right way to set it up anyhow? 
Do I need to define a new action in the controller and store the file in the views-folder?

Comment: instead use ajax and call that file and place it in the popup window.

Comment: Yep, you need to define a new action in a controller with a view, html rendered from assets is not interpolated at all. What would `@product` even mean without any controller context?

Comment: Thanks, will try to figure out how to get the ajax in place

Answer (score 0):

in your controller action do you have it responding to js and html?

```
def index
    @people = Person.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js 
    end
end
```

create a file called index.js with the code in js form which you want to render with ajax

see docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)